# Using python inside of Nuke to close Nuke

Tags: python, nuke

so I'm working in a project that requires running several things one after the other.

I'm stuck at the moment because I've managed through python (outside of Nuke) to open Nuke, load a file, run a script to update and render what I need, and now I need Nuke to save and close so the process can be marked as completed. However, I cannot find a function that will allow me to do this.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can close Nuke with Python?

Thank

I've tried things like nuke.quit(), nuke.close(), nuke.end() but the module doesn't have those attributes.

I went on the Nuke developer's guide but have been unsuccessful in finding what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Thanks

nuke.scriptExit()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).